# Does assigning an int or a float to an interface result internally in a block allocation?

Tags: go

I would like to know how Go interfaces are implemented and if it implies allocating a block on the heap when I pass an int or a float64.

Is it possible to know when it will imply an allocation ?

I ask this because I have multiple ways to implement a program, and I would prefer to pick the one that is the most efficient when the choice is easy to make *a priori*.

One design implies using an interface to pass values and I pass int, floats and a nil value. A possible design is to also pass a struct value containing an error and an int value. But I can avoid that if it’s "expensive" in memory allocation. The question is if the effort is worth it.

Note: Please don’t tell me to not optimize prematurely. I know this principle. In some situation you do want to optimize, and it is then good to know how, or how not to implement inefficient code.

Comment: It’s technically unspecified, so the best route is to profile and benchmark your code. The escape analysis will show where things are allocated, but that often is irrelevant for performance, heap allocation is not necessarily slower.

Comment: "Is it possible to know when it will imply an allocation ?" No, sorry. "I would prefer to pick the one that is the most efficient when the choice is easy to make a priori." Again: No, sorry, there is no a priori optimal way of  doing things. "Please don’t tell me to not optimize prematurely." Asking for an a priori optimum is premature optimisation. If you are concerned about performant code the best a priori advice is Don't use interface at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write **your** benchmark, it will tell you (no mem allocs **here**):

1.

```
go test -bench=. -benchmem -benchtime=1000000000x
# BenchmarkMethod1-8 1000000000 6.58  ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
# BenchmarkMethod2-8 1000000000 0.806 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkMethod1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        method1(42)
        method1(4.2)
    }
}
func BenchmarkMethod2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        method2(intOrFloat{isInt: true, i: 42})
        method2(intOrFloat{f64: 4.2})
    }
}

func method1(object interface{}) {
    switch v := object.(type) {
    case int:
        i = v
    case float64:
        f64 = v
    }
}

func method2(object intOrFloat) {
    if object.isInt {
        i = object.i
    } else {
        f64 = object.f64
    }
}

type intOrFloat struct {
    isInt bool
    i     int
    f64   float64
}

var i int
var f64 float64
```

---

2. 

```
go test -bench=. -benchmem -benchtime=100x
# BenchmarkMethod1-8  100  4202731 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
# BenchmarkMethod2-8  100  3412604 ns/op  0 B/op  0 allocs/op
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkMethod1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        outputInt = outputInt[:0]
        outputf64 = outputf64[:0]
        for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
            switch v := inputIface[i].(type) {
            case int:
                outputInt = append(outputInt, v)
            case float64:
                outputf64 = append(outputf64, v)
            }
        }
    }
}
func BenchmarkMethod2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        outputInt = outputInt[:0]
        outputf64 = outputf64[:0]
        for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
            if inputStruct[i].isInt {
                outputInt = append(outputInt, inputStruct[i].i)
            } else {
                outputf64 = append(outputf64, inputStruct[i].f64)
            }
        }
    }
}

type intOrFloat struct {
    isInt bool
    i     int
    f64   float64
}

func init() {
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            inputIface[i] = float64(i)
            inputStruct[i] = intOrFloat{f64: float64(i)}
        } else {
            inputIface[i] = int(i)
            inputStruct[i] = intOrFloat{isInt: true, i: i}
        }
    }
}

const max = 1_000_000

var inputIface = make([]interface{}, max)
var inputStruct = make([]intOrFloat, max)

var outputf64 = make([]float64, 0, max)
var outputInt = make([]int, 0, max)
```